# Can't add new device UDID to provisioning profile. Why?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Hope you could help me. I am trying to add a new device UDID to the list of iOS devices from the Member Center of [Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action). I only have the UDID associated with the device, NOT the physical device. In Member Center, I clicked on I clicked to Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles and then on Devices under the iOS Apps panel. The problem is that I cannot add the device because the Add and Edit buttons are disabled. Why is this happening?

I am ready to give you any information you need to help me address the problem.

EDIT: This is a screenshot of what I'm seeing

[image]

Comment: Click on Get Started button.

Comment: @KiritModi I still have 43 available.

Comment: Log out and open in different browser.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a member on a company account? You may not have permission to maintain UDIDs.  You could check this by trying to create a provisioning profile or App ID.  If you can't do those either, you probably do not have a high enough role. If this is the case, you will need to be an Admin or Agent role on the account.

https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on "Get Started Button"
2. Check / uncheck devices that you want
3. Check box that says you acknowledge terms and conditions
4. Hit Submit
5. Add button will be available again

I just did all those steps.

Comment: I can't even see the Get Started button. When I click on Devices > All on the left menu, the + button is disabled and it doesn't work.

Comment: then Check @jamil65able's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen in 2 cases.

case 1: you already added this device UDID. So, check if it already exist.

case 2: you have already added 100 device UDID. So, You cant add any more.

note: if one of these 2 cases are not you in, then give a screen shot.

Comment: Case 1 and 2 don't apply. The UDID is not already in the list and I still have devices addable to my provisioning profile. Provided a screenshot in the question.

Comment: add me in this skype 'jmlhossain65'

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of file, resolve the problem

Create file add yours devices :

```
Device ID   Device Name
**************UDID**********************    A - iPhone 6
****************************************    B - iPhone 6 Plus
```